# Can I compile my code in JAVA 6 And run it in JAVA 8

Tags: java, weblogic12c, tls1.2

I have to connect to a service that accepts only TLS 1.2 handshake protocols,in our organization we use java 1.6 which doesnt support TLS 1.2 ,I was thinking by compiling the java code in java 6 and have java 8 in my weblogic server can I use tls 1.2.

Comment: any code wrote with JDK6 will run on a JVM8

Answer (score 2):

> Can I compile my code in JAVA 6 And run it in JAVA 8?

**Yes**, you can.

Java versions are expected to be binary backward-compatible.
So JDK 8 can run code compiled by JDK 7 or JDK 6.

You can always refer [Compatibility Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) after a major release to check if something specific is not backward compatible